# Coming out of call back function in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a javascript array like this:
`[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]`

1,2,3 and 4,5, and 6 are my follower id's
After completing the find operation. I want to send output to browser.

Can anybody let me know how can I come out or send the result to browser?

```
 for(var i = 0; i<idName.length; i++ ) {
  tempJson = {user_id: followerId, feed_content_text: finalFeedText };
  notifications.push(tempJson);
  var conditions = {
   user_id: followerId,
   external_id: key
  };
  FeedModel.findOne(conditions, function (err, data) {
    //What condition should i write to send the output to browser when, it is done for all 'idNames'
     res.send({
        success: true,
         message: finalMsgs
        });
  });
 }
```

Comment: I want to know the "condition" that should be used inside findOne. which will be exectuted when all the iterations are performed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this following:

```
var result = [];// initialize result array
for(var i = 0; i<idName.length; i++ ) {
  tempJson = {user_id: followerId, feed_content_text: finalFeedText };
  notifications.push(tempJson);
  var conditions = {
   user_id: followerId,
   external_id: key
  };
  FeedModel.findOne(conditions, function (err, data) {
    result.push(data);//storing data in result
    if((i+1) === idName.length) { // check if all is completed
     res.send({ // sending response
        success: true,
         message: finalMsgs,
         data: result
        });
   }
  });
 }
```

Comment: I appreciate you answer. But it won't work in my case. I tried a new solution that is working fine in my case. Let me post the answer

Comment: The for loop will complete long before all `FeedModel.findOne()` functions completes. You need another variable that's only incremented in the callbacks. Alternatively, this design pattern (a counter that's incremented in callbacks to detect completion) is encapsulated by the `async.parallel()` function in async.js

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like that?

```
res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
         message: finalMsgs
        });
```

Comment: OP knows that how to send output. He wants to know that, how to send response after completion.

Answer (score 1):

This is working fine in my case:

```
var userIndex = 0;
for(var i = 0; i<idName.length; i++ ) {
  userIndex++;
  tempJson = {user_id: followerId, feed_content_text: finalFeedText     
};
  notifications.push(tempJson);
  var conditions = {
   user_id: followerId,
   external_id: key
  };
  FeedModel.findOne(conditions, function (err, data) {
     userIndex--; // It'll be 0 at the end 

      if ( userIndex == 0 ) {
         return res.send({
                success: true,
                message: finalMsgs
                });
        }
  });
 }
```

Comment: Then i suggest you to use `async.parallel()`.

Comment: Hmm, it is coming due to some other cause. next() twice.

Comment: Header already sent error comes when the header is sent twice. The same is happening in the above solution. my condition that is if(userIndex<=0) is incorrect because user-index will also have the values like 0, -1, -2 etc.